# What green and orange solids did I get when I mixed copper acetate and sodium carbonate?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution

I tried to make copper carbonate by mixing copper acetate with a sodium carbonate solution. I was expecting to see a light blue solid form at the bottom of the beaker and instead I found a green powder distributed throughout the solution. I filtered it through a coffee filter and it started turning orange. The entire coffee filter is now covered in a bright orange powder.

I need to know whether the green powder and/or the orange powder is toxic or corrosive and also what it is.

Answer (score 7):

When you mix copper(II) and carbonate, instead of getting pure $\ce{CuCO3}$ you get "basic copper carbonate," which has some amount of the carbonate replaced with hydroxide. This can range from blue to green. I've done this a few times with various salts and mixtures and I don't know what factors actually control the color. But green shouldn't be a surprise.

The most likely reason it turned orange is that some combination of your coffee filter and impurities in your chemicals ended up reducing some of it to $\ce{Cu2O}$, which is orange or red. But naturally, regardless of what this unknown substance actually turns out to be, you'll treat it as though it's toxic and handle it responsibly, right?

Comment: Does this answer change if I had used the copper acetate to electroplate a piece of nickel and it dropped some nickel into the solution or not?

Comment: If your solution is contaminated with nickel, some nickel carbonate is likely also present in the green solid. Nickel carbonate is green.