# Preparation of copper carbonate from copper acetate and sodium carbonate

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution

I reacted copper acetate with sodium carbonate. It formed a mixture of sodium hydroxide, copper carbonate, copper acetate, and copper oxide. I wanted to know if there is a process to remove the sodium hydroxide and copper oxide to leave me with just copper carbonate. I was thinking that I could wash the solution through a filter with water since sodium hydroxide is soluble and copper carbonate is not but I’m not sure if this would work. That still leaves copper oxide. Any ideas on how to get copper oxide out?

Comment: Is there a way not to make copper(I)oxide in the first place? Do you know what the reductant in your system is? In Benedict's assay, it is the aldehyde groups of sugars.

Comment: Related (followup of): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/177120/72973

Comment: I don’t know for sure

Comment: And also yes to not make copper oxide in the first place you can use copper sulfate but I did not have copper sulfate or access to sulfur or sulfuric acid. But I did have copper acetate on hand.